# Let $T: V→V$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$. Assume that $T^n = 0v$ for some $n\ge1$. Prove that the linear map $Iv + T$ is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Does $T^n$ refer to $T(T(T(\cdots T(v))))$ - $n$ total compositions of $T$?

If so, I'm not exactly sure what information this gives us on the map $T$ aside from the obvious that it slowly converges to $0v$.

And lastly, does $Iv + T$ mean $I(v) + T(v)$ which $I(v) = v$ so it would be $v + T(v)$ is an isomorphism?

$Iv$ is already known to be bijective, but what about $T$? How can we use the fact that $T^n=0v$ for some $n\ge1$ to prove that $Iv + T$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: For a basic tutorial on how to use MathJax see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hint: the good old $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+\ldots+b^{n-1})$.

Comment: Not sure what $a^n$ - $b^n$... has to do with anything, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to find a map $(I+T)^{-1}$.

Comment: I've already said I don't know what information $T^n$ = 0v gives us, so it is impossible to find a map $(I+T)^{-1}$.

Comment: Hint 2: Which is a sum of an infinite geometric progression $1+q+q^2+\dots$?